# can't load xml file in wx python RichtextCtrl

Tags: python, xml, wxpython, richtextctrl

iam new to wxpython. iam trying to load xml in richtextctrl but it's showing blank. iam using richtextctrl for display xml and images.

```
class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
 def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "A Grid", size=(500, 300))
    panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)


 self.__editor = editor = self.rtc = rt.RichTextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=(390, 388), style=0);

    bsizer = wx.BoxSizer()
    bsizer.Add(editor, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizerAndFit(bsizer)

    self.rtc.Freeze()

    xml_file = open("E:/books.xml", "r")
    xml = xml_file.read()
    xml_file.close()       

    handler = rt.RichTextXMLHandler()
    handler.SetFlags(rt.RICHTEXT_HANDLER_INCLUDE_STYLESHEET)

    rt_buffer = self.rtc.GetBuffer()
    #rt_buffer.AddHandler(handler)
    output = StringIO(xml);    

    handler.LoadStream(rt_buffer,  output)  

    self.rtc.Refresh()

    self.rtc.Thaw()

app = wx.App()
frame = TestFrame(None)
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

and i tried following method also. but still no result.

```
    self.rtc.GetBuffer().AddHandler(rt.RichTextXMLHandler())        
    stream = StringIO(xml);
    rt_buffer = self.rtc.GetBuffer()
    rt_buffer.LoadStream(stream, rt.RICHTEXT_TYPE_XML)
```

please tell me what is missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RichTextCtrl uses its own XML format according to the [documentation](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/richtextctrl_overview.html). That XML is used for styling text. This widget is not for viewing regular XML. For that, I would recommend just using a regular wx.TextCtrl.

Comment: wx.TextCtrl doesn't support images. Thanks anyway. i can show xml as string in RichtextCtrl.

Comment: You never mentioned you wanted to display images, just XML.

Comment: iam new to wxpython. iam trying to load xml in richtextctrl but it's showing blank. iam using richtextctrl for display xml and images.  see very top